# Search a record in a list without scanning all of records

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, struct

I have a List of an Record(structure) like this :

```
struct Rec
{
     int WordID;
     int NextID;
     int PrevID;
}

List<Rec>= New List<Rec>(){...};
```

I need a way to find a value of "Rec" type in List without search all of records like Binary search. I want it's time complexity be less than O(n)

Comment: Can you give us more details? What kind of search you have to perform?  You have to search by WordID?

Comment: I need to search with all of items(WordID, NextID and PrevID).I performed a binary search to a single item record with a Binary search and now I want to search it with three items.

Comment: As I said, if you have an hashtable, the search will be impressively fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to search for an item in a list is of course not having a list but having an hashtable.

If you have a dictionary instead of a list (or a dictionary AND a list) you can perform search for exact values in averaged\amortized O(1).

You can also use a binary search but only if the list is sorted, there is the method `List<T>.BinarySearch` and the search with be O(log n).

Sorting a list with n items is O(n log n).
Inserting n items in an hashtable instead is averaged O(n), inserting an item is averaged O(1).
This means that also creating the hashtable (or keeping the hashtable synchronized with the list) will be faster than sorting a list.
Consider however that hashtable consumes more memory because they have to keep internally a bucket array.

Comment: I used the BinarySearch such as this 'Rec.BinarySearch(new rec(10, 20, 30))' but I received this error : _Failed to compare two elements in the array_

Comment: This means you used a wrong comparison algorithm, you have to implement IComparable<Rec> in your structure and write a correct CompareTo implementation.

Comment: For hashtable you instead should overrite the Equals and GetHashCode methods.

Comment: And of course, before calling BinarySearch, you have to be sure the array is sorted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary search providing your list is sorted.